# how to run a single query each day by scheduling jobs

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie

I am new to hadoop. I want to run a specific query daily and get information that is stored in hive table.

How can I schedule that query to run each day by using the job scheduling and timer?

Answer (score 3):

create a shell script and run your hive query via the shell.
Put the shell script in Crontab

script.sh

```
error_handler() 
{
 echo "ERROR: $1" 1>&2 
} 

hive -f /usr/hadoop/hive_folder/hivequery.hql 
if [ $? -ne 0 ];
then error_handler "hive query failed" 
fi 

echo "Hive query completed"
```

Crontab:

```
01 00 * * * hive -f /usr/hadoop/hive_folder/script.sh   /usr/hadoop/hive_folder/job_$(date +\%Y\%m\%d.\%H\%M).log 2>&1
```

Comment: Did you find this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule it via cronjob.

First of all save your hive query in a .hql file, and then go to `crontab -e` and type something like this. This will run your Hive query every day at 00.01 AM local time.

```
01 00 * * * hive -f /usr/hadoop/hive_folder/hivequery.hql
```

Comment: yes i done this ,but how do we know cronjob is working or not and how to check output also

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an oozie job to run the above hive shell command using shell action in oozie. You can even schedule this job, as you want and can monitor the job along with logs on Hue console

Comment: If you want to go with cronjob, you can either monitor the cron logs at /var/log/cron or redirect the output of hive shell command to a log file, while setting cron